# How to stop keyup ajax call if there are no results?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I'm using .ajax call for autofill search on keyup. It starts sending call when I input more than 3 characters. I want to stop more ajax calls when there are no more results, so user can continue filling the input without a new calls everytime he writes a character.
Anyone can help ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#search-name").keyup(function () {
        var input = $("#search-name").val();
        if (input.length > 3) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/autofill_name.php",
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                    $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");
                }
            });
        }
    });
});

function selectName(val) {
    $("#search-name").val(val);
    $("#suggesstion-box").hide();
}
```

PHP Code added:

```php
if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])) {

    $keyword = $_POST["keyword"]; 
    $query ='SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ' . quote_smart($keyword,1). ' GROUP BY name ORDER BY name LIMIT 30';

    $results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);   
    if(!empty($results)) {

        echo '<ul id="user-list">';

        foreach($results as $user) {
            $username = htmlspecialchars(''.$user["name"].'', ENT_QUOTES);

            echo '<li onClick="selectName(\''.$username.'\')">'.$user['name'].'</li>';
        } 
        echo '</ul>';
    } 

}
```

Comment: have a condition on your success, if there's a results fill up or else let user type

Comment: so nobody can solve this?

Answer (score 0):

I made a little **concept** on how something like that **could** work (if I interpreted your question correctly).

Edited Javascript Code

```
$(document).ready(function () {
//0 => there are results, else equal to the text input length on which no results could be retrieved anymore.
var noMoreResults = 0;

$("#search-name").keyup(function () {
    var input = $("#search-name").val();
    var inputLength = input.length;

    if (inputLength > 3) {
        //Make a Ajax Call if there are results (noreMoreResults == 0) or if the noMoreResults is set AND the inputLength is less than the length on when no results could be retrieved anymore.
        if (noMoreResults == 0 || (noMoreResults !== 0 && inputLength < noMoreResults)) {
            noMoreResults = 0;

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/autofill_name.php",
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    //If there aren't any results.
                    if (data.length == 0) {
                        //Set noMoreResults to the input length.
                        noMoreResults = inputLength;

                        return;
                    }

                    $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                    $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

});

Edited PHP Code

```
if(!empty($_POST['keyword'])) {

$keyword = $_POST["keyword"]; 
$query ='SELECT * FROM users WHERE name like ' . quote_smart($keyword,1). ' GROUP BY name ORDER BY name LIMIT 30';

$results = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);   
if(!empty($results)) {

    echo '<ul id="user-list">';

    foreach($results as $user) {
        $username = htmlspecialchars(''.$user["name"].'', ENT_QUOTES);

        echo '<li onClick="selectName(\''.$username.'\')">'.$user['name'].'</li>';
    } 
    echo '</ul>';
} 
//Empty if there aren't any results (if this isn't the default behaviour already?).
else {
    echo '';
}
```

}

I hope this helps you out a bit.

Comment: thanks for this. The idea looks promising, but unfortunately it keeps posting new ajax calls when I continue writing next characters. 
eg. in table there is 'John' and I start writing John.. it gives me correct result, bet if I continue writing ..athan (Johnathan)  (which is not in database) it keeps posting new ajax calls every time i write a letter. So, not working

Answer (score 0):

Have a flag to indicate that there are no more results, and reset it if a new keyword prefix is inputted:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    let noResult = false;
    let minLastWord = "";

    $("#search-name").keyup(function () {
        var input = $("#search-name").val();

        if (!input.startsWith(minLastWord)) {
            noResult = false;
        }

        if ((input.length > 3) && !noResult) {
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "inc/autofill_name.php",
                data: 'keyword=' + $(this).val(),
                beforeSend: function () {
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#suggesstion-box").show();
                    $("#suggesstion-box").html(data);
                    $("#search-name").css("background", "#FFF");

                    if (data == "") {//You can create your own condition of "emptiness"
                       noResult = true;
                       minLastWord = input;
                    } else {
                       noResult = false;
                    }

                }
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, just tried your code. Sorry, this dont work aswell. When I continue writing in the input my Chrome console shows that ajax keeps posting to autofill_author.php after each character. I can write more and more characters and after each jquery sends new ajax call

Comment: What's the output of php when it has no result?

Comment: well it was ' ';  But I also tried as you wrote , my own condition,  echo = 1; and then edited your code if (data == "1") . It just keeps sending new ajax calls after each written character